# Remembering Proofs in Geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, formal-proofs

I'm taking a College Geometry class and the teacher wants us to be able to recite roughly 13 proofs on the exam. How should I try to remember those proofs? If anyone has any suggestions that would be incredible.

Comment: There is no magic potion, you need to understand those proofs. To get more help, it would be better to explicit what you are talking about.

Comment: As @Zizou23 said, there's no deep secret. In particular, I'd caution you to avoid flash cards or anything that would be appropriate for a spelling test. With proofs like these, there should be an understanding of both the overall strategy and each intricate mechanic. If you don't have that understanding, spend time thinking / asking questions until you do.

Comment: Start from what is asked and work your way to the given stuff. That is my strategy. Of course, with proofs there are multiple ways to get to the same result.

Comment: Don't memorize, understand. Remember that the mathematician who found these proofs in the first place did so without having seen them before at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think this sort of question belongs here, but nonetheless:

- Firstly, actually *learn the proofs*. Not read it over ten times but go through it meticulously enough that you understand *why each step was taken* and *the progress each step made*.

  - This is extremely crucial.
- As an obvious form of practice, recreate the proof yourself! Write down the theorem/proposition somewhere on a paper then prove it using what you learned. Now of course don't do this immediately after glancing at the proof, but an hour or more afterwards.
- Apply the proof method elsewhere, if possible. Are the different proofs *literally different methods of proof* (e.g. direct, contradiction, contrapositive, etc.)? If the teacher's goal is to have you understand different methods of proof, then practice these different methods elsewhere so you're comfortable with them.

That's all that really comes to mind without exactly knowing the proofs you're meant to learn.